# Is there a purpose of typedefing a function in C, aside from use with a function pointer?

Tags: c, function, typedef

The following code is valid C:

`typedef int math_op(int, int); // Function type definition`

The only time I've ever seen a function type declared and then used is in the case where we make a statement like the following:

`math_op *mOp = add;`

where `add` may be:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
 return a + b;
}
```

The following compiles as well given the initial declaration:
`math_op mOp;`

However, here it is not declared as a function pointer, but as a function itself. However, I know no actual usage for this and find it to be quite confusing because it seems we're declaring a function with no actual definition.

My question is, is there any *other* usage for a typedef'd function aside from using it as a function pointer type like this? Note that I am already aware of the alternative function pointer type syntax `typedef int (*math_op)(int,int);` which creates a *function pointer* type, whereas my original syntax above creates a *function type* to which we later point to.

Comment: There is no other significant usage for a function or function pointer typedef.  You cannot use a typedef like that to define a function of that type.  I suppose you could declare the function — `extern math_op add;` — but you don't often see that used (I don't recall ever seeing it used; I did a check compilation to make sure it is valid, using GCC 8.3.0 and `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [§note162](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note162) says it is allowed. But again, it is a footnote

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Thanks — I'd take that as strong support that it is intended to be valid, and GCC concurred (there's always a slight worry with GCC about whether it's an extension — but that footnote indicates that it isn't).  Noting that I needed to check also serves to underline that it is seldom used — though it certainly has merits using it.  For example: `typedef int (Comparator)(const void *v1, const void *v2); extern void qsort(void *data, size_t number, size_t size, Comparator cmp); extern Comparator cmp_str; extern Comparator cmp_int; …`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler right, it certainly has merit. Also, if I understand correctly, the third argument to `qsort` would automatically be converted to a function pointer, right?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: Yes, it would be automatically converted, but that was an unintentional mistake — I intended to use `Comparator *cmp` to be explicit.  I normally use `typedef int (*Comparator)(const void *v1, const void *v2);` with the pointer — but that notation can't be used to declare the functions.  The parentheses around `Comparator` in the other comment are also an artefact of the normal notation I use — it is harmless but unnecessary when there isn't a pointer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to clang:

> error: non-object type 'math_op' (aka 'int (int, int)') is not
>   assignable: math_op tee = 0;

So that really limits our options.

The only use I can find is if you want to forward declare a bunch of functions with the same type signature. This is probably not a good idea and would probably increase the [WTF's / line](https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/) of your code.

```
math_op tee;
int tee (int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Comment: Note that `math_op *p = 0;` would be fine.  You can't assign to functions — which is what Clang is complaining about.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that makes sense, it would be like `int add(int a, int b){return a + b;} = 0;`.... Doesn't work.

However, @cmwt I like your answer because it does provide some practical use for this. Pretty much a waste of time for just 1 function but if for some reason we needed to declare 100 functions with the same sig I guess it would be useful.